# Size of the appendix title for report

Tags: sectioning, fontsize, appendices

Is there any way I can reduce the font size of the Appendix title. Default one is creating the font size of the chapter.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,onecolumn]{report}
 \usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
 \begin{document}

  Some text: abcdef

   \appendix 
       \chapter{Appendix A: blah1}  
                   has some equations whose numbering should be A.1
       \chapter{Appendix B: blah2}  
                   has some equations whose numbering should be B.1

\end{document}
```

My current issue is I defined the appendix with \chapter and this is giving the chapter font. So I wanted to reduce this font.

a) Using local sizing using \small \LARGE are actually working. However, the header of the page is assigning to the same \small or \LARGE font size.

b) When I use \section{Appendix A} , I am getting the quation numbers as 0.1.1, etc.

Your inputs are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

One simple option is to use [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) to change the title format for chapters in the `\appendix` section; a little example in which the defaults were changed to `\large` instead of the default size for chapters (`\huge` for label, `\Huge` for title). Makje the adjustments that best suit your needs:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,onecolumn]{report}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A regular chapter}
\chapter{Another regular chapter}

\appendix
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries}% <- font for label "Appendix A", default \huge
  {\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}
  {20pt}
  {\large}% <- font for title, default \Huge

\chapter{Test apendix}  
\begin{equation}
a=b.
\end{equation}
\chapter{Appendix B: blah2}  

\end{document}
```

Compare the default size

[image]

with the size after the modification:

[image]

(both images zoomed to 150%).